# binary tree in generalized statement

Tags: haskell

I have to implement a Code which accepts a binary tree and shows a generalised Statement: this is my Code

```
mkBTree xs
    | (m == 0) = Leaf (unwrap xs)
| otherwise = Fork (mkBTree ys) (mkBTree zs)
where m = (length xs) `div` 2
      (ys, zs) = splitAt m xs
              unwrap [x] = x
```

but the only thing i get is something like:

```
Data constructor not in scope: Leaf :: a -> t
Data constructor not in scope: Fork :: t -> t -> t
```

Failed, modules loaded: none.
What is wrong here?

Comment: What is your data definition? What module did you import? and how? Is this the full program?

Comment: I imported Data.Char and Data.List and this is definition:

Comment: data mkBTree xs = Leaf xs | Fork (mkBTree xs) xs (mkBTree xs)
      deriving(Eq,Show)

    data mkBTree xs = Leaf xs | Fork xs [mkBTree xs]
      deriving(Eq,Show)

Comment: But you define `Leaf` and `Fork` twice. Can you [edit] your question and show the full code (minimal working example).

Comment: Don't add critical information as a comment or answer, edit the question and add the information there.

Answer (score -2):

I have to implement a Code which accepts a binary tree and shows a generalised Statement: this is my Code                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      import Data.Char 
       import Data.List

```
  data mkBTree xs = Leaf xs | Fork (mkBTree xs) xs (mkBTree xs)
  deriving(Eq,Show)

 data mkBTree xs = Leaf xs | Fork xs [mkBTree xs]
   deriving(Eq,Show)


entferneBlaetter :: NBaum a -> NBaum a
entferneBlaetter xs
             | (m == 0) = BBlatt (unwrap xs)
         | otherwise = BKnoten (NBaum ys) (NBaum zs)
         where m = (length xs) `div` 2
                (ys, zs) = splitAt m xs
                    unwrap [x] = x
```

Comment: 1) You cant repeat the name of the data type and constructors 2) What is NBaum type in the function? 3) What should the function do?